# How can I force Perforce (P4V) to checkout and submit with Unix line endings?

Tags: perforce, line-endings, p4v, perforce-client-spec

I'm on a Windows machine, and in my P4V `workspace:advanced-settings`, I have the following selected:

[image: workspace setting]

But I still notice extra spaces in some of my files after submitting and checking on a different machine. Is there a way to force every checkout and submission to be Unix style?

Note, I can't modify server settings, only my local workspaces.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the LineEnd to `unix` and the files you sync have `\r` characters in them, it means that somebody using `unix` submitted them in that form (i.e. the files were checked in with the understanding that the Unix version of them is supposed to have those characters in there distinct from the native line endings).  If you submit Windows-style files from a `unix`-mode workspace, you're saying that all `unix` workspaces should have Windows-style line endings for those files.  This is desirable in some instances, like when you're using Unix machines to build packages for Windows systems, but for source code that's meant to be used cross-platform it's generally a bad thing.

It's not too hard to go through the history, figure out who did that, and cluebat them (or get the admin to force a fix of their LineEnd setting so that it actually matches the contents of their workspace), and I wholeheartedly recommend doing this any time you ask for `unix` files and get a `win`-style file that you didn't want.  Usually if everyone uses the default setting of `local` everything works fine.

As far as fixing the files, a pretty easy method is to change your LineEnd to `share`, open all the files for edit, and then submit them -- the `share` setting forces all the `\r` characters to be stripped out on submit, as if you were running `dos2unix` over all your files every time you submitted.